# Align HTML DIV section properly using CSS

Tags: css, html, css-float

I am working on a webpage where I am trying to arrange 4 div areas.

1. input - user can enter data here in a form
2. output - output will be displayed here (echoing from php)
3. sumbit - contains a submit  button that can be used to submit the form data
4. save  - this section contains a save button which can be used to save\email the output section data

I am using below code to to create html:

```
<div class="input">

        INPUT
</div>

<div class="output">

             OUPUT
</div>

<div class="submit">

          SUBMIT
</div>              

<div class="save">

SAVE

</div>
```

and the css code:

```
.input{

width:45%;
float:left;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#ddd;
padding:10px;
     margin-bottom:10px;

}

.output{

width:45%;
float:right;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#ddd;
padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;

}


.submit{
width:45%;
float:left;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#ddd;
padding:10px;
     margin-bottom:10px;

}

.save{

width:45%;
float:right;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#ddd;
padding:10px;

 margin-bottom:10px;

}
```

If all `div` sections have data, they are aligning properly.But here, since `output div` area getting data from a  php script(echo the value), initially there will not be anything to display here.Due to that `divs` are not aligning properly. the `sumbit div` will occupy `output div` area.

How can i fix it ? I need to stick `submit div` eventhough there is no data in output.

I have setup a fiddle here. [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qpc6F/)  if you try removing the OUPUT from output div section, you will see the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show `.submit` *always* below `.input`, use `clear:both` on `.submit`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qpc6F/1/

(by the way, I have used `display:none` on `.output` to have the effect of empty content. Remove it in your code.)

Comment: @  mshsayem : This working with one issue : have a look into this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qpc6F/2/  if there is more data in output area, it creating gap between input and sumbut. how can I avoid that ?

Comment: In that case, how do you want to show the `.submit` div? Just below the `.input`? Also, where do you want to place the `.save` div?

Comment: .submit just below .input and .save below .output

Comment: wrap those with other container divs. Move the float and width styles to the wrappers. See if this suffices: http://jsfiddle.net/Qpc6F/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to show the border on the output div without showing any data you can just put a `&nbsp;` inside the div using the content property

```
.output:before{
    content:"\00a0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass min-height:20px;` overflow:hidden; in .output class . infact can pass this property to every class.